# Why isn't react router rendering routes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Just started learning about Routes but I'm not sure why they aren't being rendered on screen. I have v6.4 and every time I start the application I get a blank page.

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

// pages 
import Home from './pages/Home'
import About from './pages/About'

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
     <main>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<Home />}/>
        <Route path='about' element={<About />}/>
      </Routes>
     </main>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App
```

Comment: Check for any console errors in your browser's developer tools that may be causing issues.

Comment: You can try to delete <main> tag, then re-run this demo to check if there is any issue.

Comment: Fixed it! the console told me I had two instances running. Will remember to check the console for troubleshooting. Thank you!

Comment: I don't see any overt issues with the code in the snippet. Voting to close as "not reproducible or caused by typos".

Answer (score -1):

Can you try like this

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
    <Route path='/about' element={<About />} />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```